# Strange 3D Animal Movie Set in Venice?

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

- What Is It: 3D Animated Movie
- What Made It Memorable: A scene where the villain frees some leeches from a jar to drain the canals of Venice. She complains that it was rather underwhelming to release them, but then two larger, monstrous leeches come out of the water and asked what she said. She then quickly changes subject and they start to drain the water.
- When Did I See It: I was definitely around like 7-9, and it was on Netflix. Something about the “poster” used on the site scared me to death and I was terrified to watch it.
- How Old Was It: It was 3D animated, but also cheaply made, janky 3d animated, so relatively old, but still modern enough (early 2000s?)
- Part of a Series: Most likely no
- Plot: A blue dog and his friends have to stop an evil vulture(?) lady
  from gaining access to some powerful structure/item under Italy(???)
- Details:
- The movie started with the main character, a blue dog, taking to two other animals. I remember he asked exactly (throughout the movie I think they addressed the fourth wall) “Are you scared? No? Ok!” and begins reciting the film.
- A scene where the vulture villain is talking to someone (maybe a sidekick?) in a mountain or castle, surrounded by loot. She begins to talk about her evil plan, but then notices the fourth wall, and sends us away (we can still hear her plan after getting sent away).
- The above mentioned “leeches drain canals” scene.

This bizarre memory has existed in my mind for years. Would love to find a proper name to this thing.

Comment: Someone that was still 7-9 when Netflix was already a thing is now old enough to come here and ask for a movie identification. I'm feeling old.

Comment: @bracco23 Well, Netflix was a thing a long time before it became "mainstream", as far as I know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm guessing this is *Pet Pals* (2009).

Summary: "The Wicked Crow Witch has a terrible plan in mind: tarmacking the lagoon of Venice, thus turning it into a town like all the others. Will the six Pet Pals be able to put a stop to her plan and to find Marco Polo’s Code first? Will they discover in time the legendary Parallel Palace of Magic? Only the secrets contained within this palace will enable our brave Pet Pals to save Venice from this evil plan."

Trailer here:

[image]

[Company site](https://www.peekabooanimation.com/distribution/pet-pals/)